Man and daughter marooned on planet until she is kidnapped
I've been trying to recollect what movie or (mini series) I watched in the 90s.
It may have been made before the 90s, I'm not sure.
In any case, it was about a man and his pre-teen daughter. They were on this planet and he had lost his wife. He lived the life of a scavenger, trying to bring back enough to keep them afloat. 
One day he finds this strange green (I think) crystal and then his daughter is captured and taken to a space ship in lower orbit where they have other children and they're trying to perform some kind of operation on them. He rescues her and apparently has to go to some solar system, and then the movie, or episode ends and I've never seen the rest of it.
The space ship looked very much like a Nebulon-B2 frigate from Star Wars:


A green crystal.... Kryptonite? :p

I noticed that I wasn't registered at the time I posted this. The Osiris Chronicles that Matthew posted seems spot on. But unfortunately there's almost no pictures / media available of the series for me to confirm. I've tried to locate a source to obtain footage but have been unable to. The mini series appears to be almost as if it never existed. :( But thank you for posting Matthew and I'm sorry for the late response. If anyone else has further ideas please do post them.

You can go through plot details and pics here, here, here and here. Additionally, you can watch the full movie (Russian dub) to confirm. Cheers :-)

Yup, that's it. Matthew was correct and thank you rumandwrite.  I wish it wasn't dubbed :) If you ever know of a place to watch it in English do post it here.

Glad you found your movie! Whenever you're back, do select MatthewA's answer and mark this thread/page as "answered". Thanks :-)

I'd like to, but I apparently asked the question as a guest at the time I created it. I'm not sure if there's a way to claim the topic or have a moderator change it.

@Brent you're now the "owner" of the question and can mark the answer as the correct one :)

This sounds like the Osiris Chronicles.
From Wikipedia:

The story takes place several centuries in the future. Mankind has colonized the entire solar system and beyond, and hardships such as war, disease, hunger, and overpopulation have been eliminated. However, boredom spread rapidly throughout the galaxy and as a result, interstellar war broke out. The two opposing factions were the Galactic Republic and the Rebels. While the Rebels eventually defeated the Galactic Republic because of their far greater numbers, the former were no better off; the aftermath of that war was a new Dark Age. Houses, plantations, and, more importantly, most books were destroyed in the war, and knowledge of interstellar travel was mostly lost, available only to a privileged few. Mankind, in the film, had made much progress, only to be rewarded with "third world" living conditions, despite people still possessing very advanced computers.


The excerpt from Wiki does not contain any thing in common with the OP's post except for that both occur in distant future. What makes you think, this is the movie?

I remember watching it...  there's actually few hits in the plot section of the wiki. It references the scavenger bit, the pre-teen, jewels and a kidnapping. Plus the spaceship reference seems familiar.

@MatthewA - I've provided some links to the OP that should help confirm your answer. You might want to add some of that info (including the pics) to your post.
